# SQL Server union not sorting correctly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select top 1 scrr.name, sess.end_time
from tbl_session sess
     inner join tbl_scripts scrr on sess.script_id = scrr.script_id
where end_time >= '5-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and end_time < '06-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and scrr.script_type in (1,3,4)
  and sess.operator_id = 95
UNION
select top 1 scr.name, oh.end_time
from tbl_outbound_history oh
     inner join tbl_outbound o on oh.outbound_id = o.outbound_id
     inner join tbl_session ses on o.session_id = ses.id
     inner join tbl_scripts scr on ses.script_id = scr.script_id
where oh.end_time >= '5-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and oh.end_time < '06-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and oh.start_time <> oh.end_time
  and oh.user_id = 95
order by end_time
```

The data is not changing, but the result is different every time.  It's as though the order by is being ignored.

The second select returns nothing in this case and I have tried to simplify the SQL to minimise the problem, but can't reproduce it.

If I drop the second select, I get the same result every time, so something about a union to nothing and top 1 perhaps though I can't get it to do it with simpler selects.

Anybody come across such a bug before and if so, is there a workround for it.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

I'm using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
    Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: UNION doesn't sort - in fact there is no order guarantee. UNION is free to return data in whatever order is fastest. You need to apply `ORDER BY` over the entire query to get ordered results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to order & use top 1 in outer query

```
select top 1 from (
select scrr.name, sess.end_time
from tbl_session sess
     inner join tbl_scripts scrr on sess.script_id = scrr.script_id
where end_time >= '5-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and end_time < '06-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and scrr.script_type in (1,3,4)
  and sess.operator_id = 95
UNION
select scr.name, oh.end_time
from tbl_outbound_history oh
     inner join tbl_outbound o on oh.outbound_id = o.outbound_id
     inner join tbl_session ses on o.session_id = ses.id
     inner join tbl_scripts scr on ses.script_id = scr.script_id
where oh.end_time >= '5-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and oh.end_time < '06-May-2015 14:58:00'
  and oh.start_time <> oh.end_time
  and oh.user_id = 95
) a
order by a.end_time
```

Also i believe, casting datetime would be great

```
CAST('06-May-2015 14:58:00' as datetime)
```

Comment: I was hopeful, but unfortunately, it is doing the same thing.

Comment: Ohh.. Can you post the output you are getting for our reference

Comment: But, you have pointed me in the right direction - remove the top 1 from both selects and put it in the outer query and bingo - problem solved - thank you

Comment: @Graham what does "the same thing mean"? `ORDER BY` will sort by `a.end_time` ascending. If that column is datetime, the order will be chronological. If it is text, it will be alphabetical

Comment: Great :) Glad i helped in some way. Cheers !!

Comment: Pravin - edit your answer, so I can tick it as the right answer

Comment: Hi @Graham, Please check